# Testing Jsoup (Eclipse+Android programming)

Tags: android, eclipse, jsoup

I'm taking my first steps in Jsoup. Went out to read the cookbook (http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) and tried some examples unsuccessfully.

```
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org").get();
    Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");

}
```

And I'm getting the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usage: supply url to fetch
    at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
    at org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText.main(HtmlToPlainText.java:26)
```

I'm very new to programming in Java, so please have mercy :)

Comment: Are you actually testing this on Android? Because if so, you shouldn't have a main method anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Jsoup do you use? Tested the code with Jsoup 1.6.3 on Pc, works fine.

Looks like you didn't run your `main()`-Method, but the one from jsoup examples packed in the jar.

Btw. you didn't use a class:

```
// your package here

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org").get();
        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");

    }
}
```

Make shure you run this class, not the one from examples (right click on your class -> run as -> java application).